# Call ajaxform with function button

Tags: javascript, ajax

Are there a way to call a ajaxform from malsup with a function?

like this:

```
function callAjaxForm(id){

    $('#' + id).ajaxForm({
    ....
    });
 }
```

When I do such thing nothing happen...

*edited:*
I already try with a function like this:

```
function callAjaxForm(id){
    (function() {

        $('#' + id).ajaxForm({
        ....
        });
     })();
 }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Are there a way to call a ajaxform from malsup with a function?

There's no reason why you shouldn't be able to

> like this:

The [documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) shows that the method takes a function as an argument, not a plain object.

Comment: The function goes between `ajaxForm(` and `)`.